# How to counter Hellbats in the field?

Tags: starcraft-2

Usually, I scout mass Hellbats in advance. I know it is coming, but usually I lose to them.

I know they have a small range, so Marauders and Marines should outrange them. Tanks should be good, but it looks like I'm missing something and lose to mass Hellbat constantly.

I would appreciate answers for all: **how to counter mass Hellbats in TvT, ZvT, PvT** as it is really hard for me to come up with a definite answer.

Answer (score 2):

**HELLBAT**

- Costs: 100 Minerals
- Hitpoints: 135
- Armor: 0
- Light Unit
- Damage: 18 (+12 vs light) (splash radius 45)

[image]

**TvT**

- You can easily counter the Hellbat with what ever you like. If your
  enemy would go mass Hellbat, there is no way you should lose.

  If you Mech: Siege Tanks, Hellbats and Thors together with Vikings
  and Medivacs. It will always come down to who has the    most, and
  best    upgrades. Medivacs will heal your Hellbats! If you    Mech
  play as T, I always find it important to have a lot off Hellbats
  guarding my tanks.

  If you bio: Your bio has a longer range than the Hellbat, and can
  easily be kited. They die rather fast to Marauders too.

  You can also add Widow Mines along side your main army - just
  remember to get the quick burrow research!!!

**ZvT**

- Note that it is a light unit. If you are caught off guard or forgot
  to scout. Get your Banelings out ASAP. (always get Baneling speed
  upgrade)

  If you are playing a Mech Terran in general, and you scout this. You
  can go for Ling, Bling and Mutas. Again - it all comes down to number
  and how well you micro.

  But the hard counter would Banelings first, then Zerglings on the
  follow up. Mutas is again a no-brainer!

**PvT**

- Note that Hellbats eat Zealots, so forget about them if the T masses.

  Stalkers can easily kite the Hellbat. So if you would go for a
  Stalker heavy army, you shouldent have any real issues dealing with
  the Hellbats. So I will always recommend Stalkers versus mass
  Hellbats!

Comment: Hellbats were shown to be extremely dependent on initial positioning vs zerglings. I believe it was Day[9] who did the testing, and it showed that some splitting and attacks from different angles drastically decreased damage from the initial volley, and the outcome of the battle itself. **TL;DR**: split.

Comment: Also, **Derelict Watcher Balance Test Map v1.1** as of now includes a nerf to Hellbat damage to 18 flat, with +12 vs. Light coming after Blue Flame. It is not probable that this will be implemented right this way, but still a nerf might be on its way.

Comment: I would accept the answer, but for me kiting never worked vs Hellbats. I tried to use marauders, reapers, stalkers... nothing survive a strong Hellbat push. May be I'm just greedy and come to close, but i'm looking into something better than just pure outranging. Tanks, banalings - looks like a good solution. Air units probably should be mentioned here as well...

Answer (score 0):

Everything that is armored would go, and also air can be good too.
Marauders in bio (never rush marine,or u will regret it)
tanks, or thors, cyclone should beat him (mine too but make a bunch to cover the whole helion army)
banshee or bc is the best. Stalkers can be good immortals too.

You need to avoid all bio, light units, because it's what they're made for (marine,zerglings, zealots, adept).